# Looping through each column individually in a large workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large workbook with 9 sheets, each containing about 30-40 columns. I need to loop through each column individually and find values that are out of range or outliers and color them.

The only problem is that each column has unique values and I would need individual if statements for each. Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a bunch of individual for statements? I want to avoid having as many variables as possible and prevent it from taking an extremely long time to process. I have some example code of what I would need to do for each column. At the moment, all I would know how to do is repeat this code over and over for each column.

```
    Dim rngData As Range, cellData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("A2:A" & (numRows + 1))
    For Each cellData In rngData
        If cellData.Value < 0 Or cellData.Value > 200 Then
            cellData.Interior.Color = RGB(126, 206, 124)
        End If
    Next cellData
```

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: So tell us more about these unique values. They seem to be of relevance but I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @Jsheeran, that's a good suggestion, however if OP is just after some fill color, I am afraid that conditional formatting (which is volatile and will continually refresh) on 9 sheets with 30-40 columns of data which who knows how many rows, will slow down the workbook significantly.

Comment: You will need to list the rules for the columns.  Are the Rules unique by column or by column and sheet?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. To elaborate on some of the previous comments: The problem with this question is that you've not given us enough context. IF there's a pattern to the way each column is to be checked for outliers on each sheet, THEN  there might exist a smart way to check all columns, but without context, any answer to this question is nothing but a shot in the dark. Questions: 1) What's the data structure and does it vary from sheet to sheet? 2) Do all columns contain the same data type (e.g. integers)? 3) Are all columns of the same length?

Comment: @JvdV I'm working on a study so the "unique values" are number coded answers to a survey or user entered numbers. They can only fall into a certain range.

Comment: @jsheeran This is a workbook that is used for a study and repeated over multiple time periods. They are currently done by hand or with conditional formatting and I am working on making the process automatic so that it is more efficient.

Comment: @Miqi180 The workbook contains a list of subjects with certain IDs and column has an integer that is an answer to a questionnaire. Some of the columns have dates but I am only concerned about the integer values. All of the columns are the same length in each of the sheet.

Comment: @Lucas Crumb In that case, PGSystemTester's answer below should work for you with only a few modifications. For one thing, you'll need to use the `isDate()` function to filter out dates from further processing. GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the min and max changes by each column you'll have to identify them somewhere. I would put these in Excel somewhere to make it easy. However, you could also code it into VBA and have it dynamic using an array. In the below example I set up the limit for column 1. You'd have to include the min and max for all columns (which doesn't sound fun), but unless there's a dynamic method to the limits... this might be your best option.

```
Sub LoopCOLO()
Dim rngData As Range, cellData As Range, c As Long
Dim cMIN(1 To 40) As Double, cMAX(1 To 40) As Double

'Enter your min/maxex here based on column number)
    cMIN(1) = 0
    cMAX(1) = 200

    cMIN(2) = 100
    cMAX(2) = 300

'if you get confused on column nubmers you could do
    cMIN(Range("C1").Column) = 200
    cMAX(Range("C11").Column) = 300


'Loop your columns
    For c = 1 To UBound(cMAX) 'however many columns
        Set rngData = Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(numrows + 1, c))

'check values in each cell
        For Each cellData In rngData.Cells
            If cellData.Value < cMIN(c) Or cellData.Value > cMAX(c) Then
                cellData.Interior.Color = RGB(126, 206, 124)
            End If

        Next cellData
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays to store outliners and column specification like this. It is not easy to fill in the arrays but one should do it :)

```
Dim oHI(100) As Long, oLOW(100) As Long, oCnt(100) As Long
Dim oCOL(100) As Long   ' column numbers
Dim iColCnt As Long     ' number of columns to process

oCOL(0) = 1                     ' number of column #0
oHI(0) = 1000 : oLOW(0) = 200   ' high-low pairs for column #0
oCnt(0) = 44                    ' count of valid elements in column #0

oCOL(1) = 5                     ' number of column #1
oHI(1) = 100 : oLOW(1) = 0
oCnt(1) = 60

...
iColCnt = <count of columns to be processed, 0 relativ>

For i = 0 to iColCnt
    Set rngData = Range(Cells(2, oCOL(i), Cells(oCnt(i) + 1, oCOL(i))
    For Each cellData In rngData
        If cellData.Value < oLOW(i) Or cellData.Value > oHI(i) Then
            cellData.Interior.Color = RGB(126, 206, 124)
        End If
    Next cellData
```

Supposing all outliners are integers.